# How to add user controller when using ui-router with nested views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router` with nested views to display a few tables with user data on a user profile page. Here is an overview of the routes:

routes.config.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.routes').config(routesConfig);

    routesConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'RouteHelpersProvider'];
    function routesConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, helper){

        // Set the following to true to enable the HTML5 Mode
        // You may have to set <base> tag in index and a routing configuration in your server
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

        // defaults to dashboard
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');

    // 
    // Application Routes
    // -----------------------------------   
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
          url: '/app',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: helper.basepath('app.html'),
          resolve: helper.resolveFor('fastclick', 'modernizr', 'icons', 'screenfull', 'animo', 'sparklines', 'slimscroll', 'classyloader', 'toaster', 'whirl','loaders.css', 'spinkit','jquery-ui', 'jquery-ui-widgets','weather-icons', 'skycons')
      })
      .state('app.home', {
          url: '/home',
          title: 'Home',
          templateUrl: helper.basepath('home.html'),
      })
      .state('app.user', {
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: helper.basepath('user.html'),
          // controller: 'UserPageController',
          // controllerAs: 'userCtrl',
          resolve: helper.resolveFor('datatables')
      })
      .state('app.user.dashboard', {
          url: '/user',
          title: 'User',
          controller: 'UserPageController',
          controllerAs: 'userCtrl',
          views: {
            'eventTable': {
              templateUrl: helper.basepath('userProfile/eventTable.html'),
              controller: 'EventTableController',
              controllerAs: 'eventCtrl'
            },
            'bankStatement': {
              templateUrl: helper.basepath('userProfile/bankStatement.html'),
              controller: 'BankStatementController',
              controllerAs: 'bankCtrl'
            },
            'purchasesTable': {
              templateUrl: helper.basepath('userProfile/purchasesTable.html'),
              controller: 'PurchasesTableController',
              controllerAs: 'purchasesCtrl'
            },
            'paymentsTable': {
              templateUrl: helper.basepath('userProfile/paymentsTable.html'),
              controller: 'PaymentsTableController',
              controllerAs: 'paymentsCtrl'
            },             
            'clicksTable': {
              templateUrl: helper.basepath('userProfile/clicksTable.html'),
              controller: 'ClicksTableController',
              controllerAs: 'clicksCtrl'
            }, 

          }
      });
    } // routesConfig

})();
```

When I try to add another controller to display the user's basic info(I have tried adding the controller to `app.user` and `app.user.dashboard`) the controller is never activated. Here is the rest of the relevant code:

user.html

```
<h3 class="fixedSubHeader">{{userCtrl.userInfo}}</h3>
<section ui-view="eventTable"></section>
<section ui-view="bankStatement"></section>
<section ui-view="paymentsTable"></section>
<section ui-view="purchasesTable"></section>
<section ui-view="clicksTable"></section>
```

userPage.controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.userPage')
        .controller('UserPageController', UserPageController);

    UserPageController.$inject = ['$resource'];
    function UserPageController($resource) {
        var vm = this;
        activate();
        // console.log("USER!!!!!");

        ////////////////

        function activate() {

          // Ajax

          $resource('server/basic-info-table.json').query().$promise.then(function(userInfo) {
             vm.userInfo = userInfo;

          });
        }
    }
})();
```

I originally thought this was a problem with the userPage controller so I tried injecting `$scope` and getting rid of the `var vm = this` syntax. This approach, however, also did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you are trying to use one controller `UserPageController` for all of the ui-views, and then they have their own controller.

So I assume you want `UserPageController` to be the parent controller to all of those ui-views. To do this, those should all be their own states. Make them a child state of `app.user.dashboard`.

For example:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('app.user.dashboard', {
          url: '/user',
          title: 'User',
          controller: 'UserPageController',
          controllerAs: 'userCtrl'
      })
      .state('app.user.dashboard.eventTable', {
          views: {
              'eventTable@dashboard': {
                  templateUrl: helper.basepath('userProfile/eventTable.html'),
                  controller: 'EventTableController',
                  controllerAs: 'eventCtrl'
              }
          }
      },
      // Repeat the other states here...
      );
```

And in `user.html`, you can use a ui-view like so:

`<section ui-view="eventTable@dashboard"></section>`

Now every child state of `app.user.dashboard` will have the parent controller of `UserPageController` which they can inherit from, while they can also have their own controller.

If you are on the `app.user.dashboard` state and you transition to `app.user.dashboard.eventTable`, you will still be on `app.user.dashboard`, however now the `app.user.dashboard.eventTable` will be a sort of "child state" within the parent state, without having to leave the parent state, at least in terms of the UI.

---

Be aware that if you don't have any sort of default content on `app.user.dashboard`, then you would want to transition to some default child state so you aren't left with some empty screen.

You can do this by first adding a default param in your `app.user.dashboard` state:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('app.user.dashboard', {
          url: '/user',
          title: 'User',
          controller: 'UserPageController',
          controllerAs: 'userCtrl'
          defaultChildState: 'app.user.dashboard.eventTable'
      })
      // ...
```

...and then in your `run` block, add something like this:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
        if (toState.defaultChildState) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go(toState.defaultChildState, toParams);
        }
    });
```

The above code will basically check for the `defaultChildState` property when you go to `app.user.dashboard`, and then it will go to that state. So any time you go to `app.user.dashboard`, you are actually going to `app.user.dashboard.eventTable`, or whatever other default state you name.